# Passing argument to subset() and unique()

Tags: r, parameter-passing, subset, phyloseq

I am using the phyloseq package.

```
test <- function( ...){

bar <- unique(sampleData[,'pH'])

foo <- subset_samples(phyloseqObject, pH == as.numeric(bar[1]@.Data))
print(foo)

}

test(pH)
```

I want to pass **pH** as an argument to `test()` but `unique()` won't accept it as valid. I can pass **'pH'** to `test()` but `subset_samples()` won't accept that as valid. I have tried coercing the argument to several different types with no luck.

SORCE for subset_samples:

```
subset_samples <- function(physeq, ...){
    if( is.null(sample_data(physeq)) ){ 
        cat("Nothing subset. No sample_data in physeq.\n")
        return(physeq)
    } else {
        oldDF <- as(sample_data(physeq), "data.frame")
        newDF <- subset(oldDF, ...)
        if( class(physeq) == "sample_data" ){
            return(sample_data(newDF))
        } else {
            sample_data(physeq) <- sample_data(newDF)
            return(physeq)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you use?: `bar <- unique(sampleData$pH)`

Comment: @desc That works for `unique()` but I still can't pass to `subset()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on what @desc said I managed to solve it like this:

```
test <- function(...){

    bar <- unique(sampleData[,...])

    foo <- subset_samples(phyloseqObject, eval(parse(bar@names)) == as.numeric(bar[1]))
    print(foo)

}

test('pH')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
test=function(x,...){
   bar=unique(mtcars[,x])
   foo=subset(mtcars,mtcars[,x]==bar[1])
   return(foo)
}
```

Comment: But that `subset()` call goes through `subset_samples()` in my case and that function wants a logical expression. I need to use it that way because of the way the phyloseq-class is built.

Comment: Added source to `subset_samples()` for clarity.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: great! glad to help!